# Calling parameterized constructor of super class with different datatype in java?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public abstract class Polygon {
    private List<Double> sides;
    
    public Polygon(List<Double> sides)
    {
        this.sides=sides;
    }

    public List<Double> getSides() {
        return sides;
    }
    
}

public class Square extends Polygon{
    public Square(Double side1) {
        // here i want to call super(sides). how do i convert double(side1) to list. 
    }
}
```

I want to call the constructor of polygon class from square class but how do i convert double to list?

**Note**: I cannot change any datatype.

Comment: Perhaps something like `Arrays.asList(side1, side1, side1, side1)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a list with that one double repeated four times:

```
super(Arrays.asList(side1, side1, side1, side1));  //java 8
super(List.of(side1, side1, side1, side1));        //java 9+
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code, will convert your double to a list, which can be used as a parameter to invoke the constructor.

```
DoubleStream.of(doublesArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

doublesArray is the Double param

Comment: What is `doublesArray`? The OP doesn't have an array.